# how set the request timeout in asp .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, publish, request-timed-out

- From the Visual Studio select Create a new project. Select ASP.NET Core 3.1
- Publish and Host in IIS
- Increase upload file size this code :

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MaxRequestBodySize = 314572800;
    });

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

and web config:

```xml
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <!-- This will handle requests up to 300MB -->
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="314572800" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

The above applies correctly but the default timeout is 2 min

How can I increase the timeout in ASP.NET Core 3.1 app hosted in IIS?

Note: my web.config

```xml
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\AspCoreTestFileUpload.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

for requestTimeout :
Doesn't apply to in-process hosting. For in-process hosting, the module waits for the app to process the request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attributes-of-the-aspnetcore-element

**I have to use inprocess hostingModel**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

issue is solved:

in web config :

```xml
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <!-- This will handle requests up to 300MB -->
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="314572800" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and in asp core 3.1 ConfigureServices :
I did not understand the reason, but this piece of code solved the problem

```cs
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue; // <-- ! long.MaxValue
    options.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    options.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
    options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```