# angular application http client issue after two minutes

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a angular application that working with net core 3 backend api.

In the production environment an http request (if request takes more than 2 minutes) get **"(failed)net::ERR_FAILED"** at network status after 2 minutes and at console screen application thrown and CORS error when only http request failed.

**from origin 'http://abc.qwer.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

But in the development environment I don't have any of these issues.

Net core web api running on IIS.

Is this a timeout problem ? Any idea how to resolve it ?

[image]

Comment: `CORS` issue need to be resolved from backend.

Comment: yes but I am getting CORS issue only one http request that if takes longer than 2 minutes. I have added the screen shot.

Comment: May me this is the answer for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296859/how-set-the-request-timeout-in-asp-net-core-3-1

Comment: @SantoshShinde still same result

Comment: I have changed hostingModel="outofprocess" to hostingModel="inprocess" and no error thrown

Comment: Is that working API and having a problem with API's are hosted on the same server.

Comment: Yes it's working API in production I just changed the hosting model of net core web api (to in process) and CORS and timeout problem has gone. API and angular application working on same server

Comment: make sure you have set the requestTimeout at web.config file if you use kestrel  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Instead, create an answer or delete the question please.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED :**

if you use IIS as proxy and hosting net core api or web application behind it you should check web.config file. If your request takes longer tahen default timeout value which 2 min. then add requestTimeout value to web.config file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-5.0